# Mechanicalsoup Catpcha issue on submit Python

Tags: python, asp.net, bots, captcha, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to create a bot in python using mechanicalsoup to scrape a trademark status details from -

http://ipindiaonline.gov.in/eregister/Application_View.aspx

This site is made up on asp.net technology so it will contain "VIEW_STATE" etc other form parameters. Using mechanical soup, I have successfully automated application to the captcha page, but after submitting the form without captcha it's giving an object error (I have attached screenshot of this error as well). Since I want to bypass captcha because mechanicalsoup doesn't use javascript so it can be done using it only and "I HAVE ALREADY DONE IT" on other captcha secured website,but here I'm getting this error due to javascript object created "onSubmit" function of this form.

I'm unable to figure out how to simulate javascript required to make it work or any other work around.

Please don't suggest using selenium or phantomJS unless it can be done without captcha.

Here is my basic approach/code in python so far..

```
import mechanicalsoup 

baseURL = "http://ipindiaonline.gov.in"
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open(baseURL+"/eregister/Application_View.aspx")
form = browser.select_form('form[action="./Application_View.aspx"]')
browser['rdb'] = "N"
response = browser.submit_selected()
form = browser.select_form('form[action="./Application_View.aspx"]')
browser['applNumber'] = "321567"
response = browser.submit_selected()
with open("demo.html","w") as f:
  f.write(str(browser.get_current_page())) 
exit();
```

Error png -

[Object reference error image(png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgd2R.png)

Answer (score 1):

MechanicalSoup was written to help automate things on websites, but not to bypass measures to avoid bots on websites, which is precisely what you're trying to do. There are probably technical ways to do what you're looking for, but 1) they will most likely violate the terms of service of the website, and 2) MechanicalSoup won't help you much here.

Comment: Thanks..I admire your concern.
But my solution demands bypassing the captcha.